# Electromagnetism: Calculating work required to assemble two parallel planes of different charge

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

For a configuration of two large parallel conducting planes of area A, h meters away from each other, and one having charge Q and another having charge -Q, I learnt that the electric field between them is roughly $E = \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$.

The question is how much work does it take to create this configuration?

I know one way to calculate is to integrate based on volume:

$$U = \int \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0 E^2 dV = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0\left(\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}\right)^2 Ah = \frac{1}{2}QV$$

where the final $V$ is the potential difference between the two plates.

Is there another way to calculate the same $U$?

Answer (score 1):

One way is going from the general definition of work. It is known that for discrete systems of $N$ point charges, the work needed to assemble the configuration is $$W=\frac{1}{2}\sum_k^N q_k V(r_k)$$
where $V(r_k)$ is the potential at the position of the charge $q_k$ due to all the other charges.
In the continuous limit, this instead becomes $$W=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\text{charge}} Vdq=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\text{distribution}} V\rho  \,d\tau$$

This integral is taken over the charge distribution and might be a line, surface or volume integral depending on what kind of distribution you have.

Then in your case, $$W=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\text{plates}} V \sigma \,dA$$
You have to calculate the potential from the electric field, which readily gives you $$V(x,y,z)=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}z$$ (for simplicity we set the potential at one of the plates to be null) and the work gives you $$W=\frac{1}{2}\sigma V A=\frac{1}{2}Q\,V$$

Comment: thanks! is there a place where I can see the derivation for the work equation?

Comment: @Helpme see Griffiths's _Introduction to Electrodynamics_

Comment: i see, thanks for the reply!